# checking if a particular substring is present in the string(present in the row of dataframe)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Trying to find the substring in the columns of pandas dataframe.

Below is my code

```py
    import pandas as pd

    list1=[1,2,4,5,6,10]

    list2=[3,5,86,7,6,20]

    list3=['ABC , CDE','CDE','XYZ' , 'cde','XYZ , EFG , CDE qw','IJK']

    df1=pd.DataFrame({'col1':list1,'col2':list2,'col3':list3})

    D=df1[df1.col3.str.contains('CDE', case=False)]

    print('\n \n \n ',D)

    print('\n \n \n ',df1)
```

orginal dataframe :

```
col1    col2    col3
1   3   ABC , CDE
2   5   CDE
4   86  XYZ
5   7   cde
6   6   XYZ , EFG , CDE qw
10  20  IJK
```

Output dataframe :

```
col1    col2    col3
1   3   ABC , CDE
2   5   CDE
5   7   cde
6   6   XYZ , EFG , CDE qw
```

What I need :

```
col1    col2    col3
1   3   ABC , CDE
2   5   CDE
5   7   cde
```

I dont want the col3 which has 'XYZ , EFG , CDE qw'. I want to be able to differentiate 'CDE qw' with 'CDE'.

In simple I want to iterate over the string in col3 and find the exact string.

When I use `D=df1[df1.col3.str.match('CDE', case=False)]`  instead of `D=df1[df1.col3.str.contains('CDE', case=False)]`

The output will be

```
2   5   CDE
5   7   cde
```

but I wan to have other rows which have CDE.

I believe I should be using regex and split for pandas. But I am not sure how to iterate through over all the sub string for a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a list comprehension

```
mask = [any([sub.lower() == 'cde' for sub in item.split(' , ')]) for item in df1.col3]
df1[mask]
```

---

You can also use

```
df1[(pd.DataFrame(df1['col3'].str.lower().str.split(' , ').tolist()) == 'cde').any(1)]

    col1    col2    col3
0   1       3       ABC , CDE
1   2       5       CDE
3   5       7       cde
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
import re
def func(data_s):
     reg = re.compile(r"[C]+D[E]+\Z", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
     res = filter(reg.search, [x.strip() for x in data_s.split(',') if x]) 
     return bool(res)

df1[df1['col3'].apply(func)]

Output
   col1  col2       col3
0     1     3  ABC , CDE
1     2     5        CDE
3     5     7        cde
```

Comment: Same problem as the other answer ;)

Comment: How can I add a list of search words? reg = re.compile(r"[C]+D[E]+\Z", flags=re.IGNORECASE)